# Drupal: Split View by Date

Tags: drupal, view

I'm currently working on a small website with a list of course dates.

I am using Drupal 7 with views for this. I made a view where all courses are sorted by dates, which is a quite long list, so I'm thinking of adding a headline, with the month between the headlines.

For example, now my list looks like this:

- Course 1
- Course 2
- Course 3
- ...

And I want to have:

January

- Course 3
- Course 4

February

- Course 3
- Course 4

I'm quite new to drupal and so I hope anybody can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is working. In drupal views you can group your fields by a field value. I found a screencast which explains how to do it:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cp2SPiwA2Qg